# NodeJS and exports "has no method .."

Tags: javascript, node.js, replace

Im writing an api for project and got a rare error with this function

```
exports.getSummonerId = function(sum, callback) {

   var summoners = {};
   var summoner = sum.replace(/\s+/g, '');

   request("https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/"+region+"/v1.4/summoner/by-name/"+summoner+"?api_key="+api_key, function(error, response, body) {
         summoners[summoner] = JSON.parse(body);
         callback(summoners[summoner][summoner].id);
   });
}
```

The call is:

```
var lol = require('./apiwrapper.js');


lol.getSummonerId(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

I get:

```
lol-test/apiwrapper.js:11
   var summoner = sum.replace(/\s+/g, '');
                      ^
TypeError: Object function (data) {
   console.log(data);
} has no method 'replace'
```

If I run the code without the exports, directly from apiwrapper.js everything runs normal.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I'm not wrong `lol.getSummonerId` takes two parameters, and you are passing just one. Which is a `function` and I don't think that has a function **replace**.

Comment: LoL, thanks, n00b mistake.Thats what happens when you program 20hs straight. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function has 2 parameters, summoner name and callback function. Try this:

```
lol.getSummonerId("player", function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Yes, that was it, rookie mistake, 20hs programming nonstop. thanks